# How to build desktop application that work with Verifone or Ingenico EMV Device

Tags: java, desktop-application, emv, verifone

I see places like whole food are using windows desktop application(maybe c# or java, I don't know) and verifone emv device to accept customer payment.

Our company wants to do the same thing. The problem is we don't know how Verifone device connects to the desktop application. Does anyone have clues how the verifone device talk to Desktop POS application?

Comment: too broad 
Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry about that, after search a lot, I still don't have enough clue how to start. That's why my question is very broad.

Comment: To answer the question that was asked: NACS-XML.

Comment: Hello, Can you tell me if you have found the proper SDK to connect to Verifone using C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets split it into two entities, (1)The POS where you enter the amount and what prints the receipt.(2)the terminal, where the card transaction happens.

Check with VeriFone on SDK that you can use to integrate your POS with the terminal. Once integration is over (1)once payable amount is ready at POS, sent the amount to terminal using the API provided by VeriFone so that you do not have to manually enter the amount (2)Once the amount is received by terminal, it can ask for the card and continue like usual and finally update the status back to POS. (3) the POS based on the result provided by the terminal decides whether the transaction is successful or not.

Normally POS connects to terminal, not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Really helpful. I have another 2 questions: VeriFone and Ingenico only work with banks? Or they can also work with paypal, stripe. If they only works with bank, do we need to talk to the bank to figure out the rates for each transaction? Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing that terminal vendors will work only with banks, they run business and anything which generates revenue should be ok for them. Since terminal is always connected to acquirers and acquirers are normally banks, it can look so. But I am not quite sure how PayPal and Ingenico /Verifone is linked here as the former is mostly for card not present transactions and the later for card present transactions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. We will take this into consideration when developing POS, thank you